# Show Validation Summary in AngularJS on Form Submit

Tags: angularjs, validation

Is it possible to show a Validation Summary, a Div on top of the page with all the Validation error messages in angularjs , on form submit ?

I am coming from a .Net background and used to have a validation summary concept,all the examples i have seen in angular shows the error message right next to the control.

I am very new to angularjs , so an example or pointer to the right direction would be appreciated !

Thanks !

Comment: Have you seen this [article](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angularjs-form-validation)?

Comment: Put the error messages at the top, in a hidden div, the same way as the examples you have seen and make the div visible when submitting the form.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks ! for now looks like that is my only option. But i want to show the div only on Form submit.

Comment: `$scope.submit = function() { if ($scope.theForm.$invalid) { $scope.errorMessagesDivVisible = true; } }`

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can use flags on each of your input fields, which will show a specific error message based on whether that flag is true or false.

For example:

```
 <div ng-controller="signupCtrl">
     <input type="text" id="username">
     <input type="text" id="password">
     <button ng-click="validate()">Sign-up</button>
 </div>
```

Then, the validate function would run several other functions that would set flags. For example:

```
function signupCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.validate = function() {
         if( /* username is bad */ ) {
             $scope.usernameError = true;
         } else if ( /* password is bad */ ) {
             $scope.passwordError = true;
         } else {
             // AJAX call to submit sign-up, or whatever
         }
    }
}
```

Your error messages would look like this:

```
<div class="error" ng-show="usernameError">Your username is bad</div>
<div class="error" ng-show="passwordError">Your password is bad</div>
```

Or, better yet, you can use a model, and only one error message:

```
<div class="error" ng-show="error">You {{field}} is bad</div>
```

But that second option would require some different tweaking of your code.